# SSH: Dismiss read mail messages from Cron

Tags: ssh, email, cron

Whenever I ssh to my server box, I get 'You have mail' along with banner message.
Then I type mail, and go through msgs, by hitting enter, until At EOF shows up,
and when I do quit or ctrl+d, and re-login to my server, I get same msg about You have mail...

Is there a manual for that mail utility?

Comment: Have you tried `man mail` in the SSH terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The manual is usually accessible using `man mail`, as with any other program.

You can tell it to delete all messages by entering `d *`, or just mark them as read with `seen *`.

The messages themselves are stored in `/var/mail/$USER` (or `/var/spool/mail/$USER`). If you have a MTA installed and configured, you can forward them to your real mailbox (e.g. Gmail) by putting the email address in the `~/.forward` file.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to not receive messages from individual cron jobs, you can redirect output at the end of each line in your crontab--e.g. `> /dev/null` for just stdout (you'll still get stderr messages in the mailbox) or `&> /dev/null` to redirect everything to the bit bucket*. If you don't want any messages from cron at all in your mailbox, add `MAILTO=""` to the beginning of your crontab.

*though right now I'm having an issue trying to stop cron from sending a message when a running cron script is killed. In that case, only the `MAILTO` thing seems to work right now to prevent an email.